# How to provide page_template path in custom plugin using WordPress

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, plugin-development, templates, page-template

How we can provide page_template path in custom plugin using WordPress?

I given a path in page_template='templatepage/checkoutpage.php' as array of post.Inserting post data by wp_insertpost() function.But page_template value of path is not triggered and not displaying the php template file.I created a custom template page and it's not triggering.

Please give suggestions for my question.

Comment: Where is the file `templatepage/checkoutpage.php` located? In your active theme or in a a plugin? Are you trying to apply this template to a `page` or to a custom post type?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that inserts a post using `wp_insert_post`. In the process, it specifies the page template for the post using the `page_template` parameter. The path to the template is relative to theme directory.

```
function wpse415873_insert_page(){
  
  $post = array(
    'post_content'          => 'This page was generated with wp_insert_post',
    'post_title'            => 'WPSE415873 Test Title',
    'page_template'         => 'page-templates/full-width.php',
    'post_type'             => 'post'
  );
  
  global $wpdb;
  $query = $wpdb->prepare( 
    "SELECT * 
    FROM $wpdb->posts 
    WHERE post_title=%s
    AND NOT post_status=%s
    AND NOT post_status=%s", 
    "WPSE415873 Test Title", 
    'inherit', 
    'trash' 
  );

  $posts = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
  
  if ( !count($posts) ){
    wp_insert_post( $post );
  }
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse415873_insert_page' );
```

Make sure the `Template Post Type` declaration in the file header of your page template includes the type of post you are inserting. For instance, my full-width.php template has the following header which allows it to apply to both posts and pages:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Full-width
 * Template Post Type: post, page
*/
```

The reason for the database query is to figure out if the post already exists in some form other than a trashed post or revision. If so, we probably don't want to insert it again.